# Guidance on Writing a Function to Automate Repetitive Steps

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that automates a series of steps I am trying to take to restructure and summarize different variables so that they are easier to visualize. I have limited experience writing my own functions though and am not sure if I am taking the right approach to do this. I would appreciate any help anyone can offer to help me get my function working.

agent_data_clean is the data frame I am working with, the remaining names are variable names from the data frame.

This is the code I am trying to automate:

```
agent_col_names <- c("region", "Impression", "code", "counts", "question")

agent_q2a <- agent_data_clean %>% group_by(region, Impression, `The 
formal training you received in EDGE`) %>% summarise(counts = n()) 
%>% mutate(question = "The formal training you 
received in EDGE")

colnames(agent_q2a) <- agent_col_names

agent_q2b <- agent_data_clean %>% group_by(region, Impression, `The in- 
person, instructor-led training`) %>%
summarise(counts = n()) %>% mutate(question = "The in-person, instructor- 
led training")

colnames(agent_q2b) <- agent_col_names

agent_q2c <- agent_data_clean %>% group_by(region, Impression, `The E- 
learning training (GU Courses)`) %>%
summarise(counts = n()) %>% mutate(question = "The E-learning training 
(GU Courses)")

colnames(agent_q2c) <- agent_col_names

agent_q2 <- bind_rows(agent_q2a, agent_q2b, agent_q2c)
```

This is a copy of the function I was trying to get to work to automate the above steps:

```
test <- function(df, grp_constant, grp_vars, col_names) {
for(i in seq_along(grp_vars)) {
result <- list()
grp[i] <- c(grp_constant, grp_vars)
result$agent_q[i] <- df %>% group_by(grp[i]) %>% summarise(counts = n()) 
%>% mutate(question = as.character(grp_vars[i]))
colnames(agent_q[i]) <- col_names
return(result)}}
```

Comment: The [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) package vignette is the best place to start when you're trying to program with `dplyr`. It's a bit more complicated than programming in base R.

Comment: I'd recommend reading through that (a couple times, probably) and making another attempt. If you still have trouble, post a new question showing your attempts (using the quosures described in the help) **and** including sample data.

Comment: And this https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/

Comment: Thanks for the links! Was able to get the dplyr portion of the code working, which is a big help in cleaning things up!! Still not able to take the function all the way I wanted, but I think I just need to practice more with for loops before I can take it to the next level.